# Where are the bearings in thru axle hubs?

Tags: mountain-bike, hub, mechanical, bearings, through-axle

So I’ve looked all over the internet to find an anatomy picture of a thru axle hub, because I don’t understand where the bearings go, and I can’t find anything helpful.

Can anyone help me understand where the bearings are in a thru axle hub? Maybe show a picture. I just want to know.

Comment: There are several different designs.  Some have loose bearings that you can disassemble to service, others have bearing cartridges that must be replaced as a single piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at diagrams of any hub. Through-axle bearings are basically in the same places as on quick release hubs. On a through axle hub the bearings, and the hollow axle, are simply of greater diameter than on a quick release hub.

Googling 'through axle hub bearing' provided a number of diagrams for me.

Googling 'through axle hub bearing replacement' for videos also got some interesting results. Try this one from Park Tool where they disassemble a TA hub with loose rather than cartridge bearings.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks for showing the video, it really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Many thru axel designs use cartridge bearings, which are not servicable (one replaces the cartridge bearing-- no more loose balls smushed in a greased filled cup and held in place by adjusting a cone nut).  [Here](https://forums.mtbr.com/attachments/tooltime/1039444d1451677956-adjusting-shimano-thru-axle-hubs-hb-m618.png) and [Here](https://forums.mtbr.com/attachments/tooltime/1039443d1451677953-adjusting-shimano-thru-axle-hubs-fh-m618.png) are schematics from Shimano of a rear and front hub featuring thru axels.  This particular model uses caged bearings, and I've selected this for clarity as the bearing balls are obvious and not hidden within a cartridge package.

Comment: I'm unsure how to actually include the drawings of these hubs within the body of my answer. Might be beneficial to edit the drawings within the body as these links could break in the future.

Comment: There's an axle on these pictures on which the bearings run. But is this axle the thing you pull out to remove the wheel, or is that an extra part not shown that goes in additionally, much like QR skewer?

Comment: The axle in these drawings is the shaft through which the removable thru-axle is inserted when attaching the wheel.